# Can't start ejabberd after hostname change

Tags: debian, xmpp, ejabberd

When I try start ejabberd service it always crashes.

```
Starting jabber server: ejabberd
Crash dump was written to: /var/log/ejabberd/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})

Crash dump was written to: /var/log/ejabberd/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
.
```

I've changed hostanme of server, before that it worked fine, however in config I have:

```
{hosts, ["localhost", "private.localhost", "public.localhost"]}.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't just simply change the hostname as Erlang/ejabberd has problems with that.

Try this approach (**sledgehammer style**)

- Switch back to your original hostname
- Dump ejabberd Erlang database `ejabberdctl backup /tmp/ejabberd_bkp` (permission problems can occur if you choose another output directory)
- Backup your ejabberd config(s)
- Uninstall ejabberd
- Change your hostname to your current hostname
- Install ejabberd
- Import your database with `ejabberdctl restore /tmp/ejabberd_bkp`

Comment: yeah, I've ended with pretty much this approach, watching erlang core dumps ain't very amusing. thanks